# How to get video thumbnail (frame) from live video url

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, thumbnails

I have video uploaded on server. which is trailer of movie. I can play this video direct to my videoView with the help of live url. My question: is there any method in android which help me out to get a video frame from url without **download** the video to local storage. I know one method name "createvideothumbnail" but it will not work in my case. because i need to get the video thumbnail without download the whole video. as you have seen the mechanism is implemented in imdb official app (Trailer section).

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Getting thumbnails without download the complete video is not possible until now (`API Level 22`) i´m pretty sure that the application that you describe load thumbnails that were created previously.

the current option would be using the class:

```
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails;
```

or create the thumbnails in a separated process.