# how get frame from video url and show in ImageView

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-glide

I use glide to get frame from video url but glide for get frame, download the whole video and it takes time.

```
        RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
            .fitCenter()
            .centerCrop().circleCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_circle);

       Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .apply(myOptions)
            .load(Link)
            .into(image);
```

How can I get the last frame from the video?

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954894/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `MediaMetadataRetriever` for doing that , you can also use **url** ,  code sample from [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/05/get-image-frame-in-video-using.html) ,

.....

```
String url = "yoururl";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ImageView capturedImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.capturedimage);

  MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

  mediaMetadataRetriever .setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
  Bitmap bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1000); //unit in microsecond
  capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(bmFrame);
 }
```

Comment: tnx. but this use for internal video . i want to get frame from link

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you need this api to first fetch the frame separately and then use the glide
[How to get video thumbnail (frame) from live video url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224416/how-to-get-video-thumbnail-frame-from-live-video-url)